# Running a Tornado Web server (on an actual server, not just locally)

Tags: ssh, server, tornado

This is my first time I am working with a web server. I have a **.py** programme which is my **Tornado server** that successfully handles requests. I have tested it out on my local machine and then sent it to my hosting. I ran the programme in an **SSH-session** and it **worked** perfectly fine, but after I had **quit the SSH-session**, the **Tornado server stopped**. Now I would really like to know what is ***the right way to run the Tornado service on my server.***

Comment: It makes most sense to write a startup script and operate your process like any other daemon. You can use an existing script, maybe from an apache http server and modify it to your means. Then you register the service with the means used by the operating system you use.

Comment: You can try to use `nohup` to detach your server from tty (console), so server will operate after you dropped your ssh session. Proper way is defined by your hosting provider, IMHO.

Comment: @dmitry_romanov Hi. Thank you for your response. Hosting provider, 1gb.ru, has some Wiki on Python, Django, Pylons and so on, but nothing of this seems to help me. I will try nohup, though. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you for your reply. I will try to set up a startup programme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It primarily depends on he type of deployment you have in mind. If you have a full server available you can use [`supervisor`](http://supervisord.org/), as suggested by [billy_lu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3680194/billy-lu); for a more robust setup you may put your Tornado server behind Nginx acting as a [load balancer](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html#running-behind-a-load-balancer).

On the other hand, some providers don't give you full access, and require Python web apps to serve using the WSGI protocol; a good example is Google App Engine. In this case you need to wrap your Tornado app in a `WSGIAdapter`; something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import tornado.httpserver
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.server_port, address=options.server_address)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
else:
    import tornado.wsgi
    app = tornado.wsgi.WSGIAdapter(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

1: [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) is what you are looking for. *Supervisor is a client/server system that allows its users to monitor and control a number of processes on UNIX-like operating systems.*

2: Just like nohup, you can use `tmux` to run your server in the background, and it provids a lot other fetures to make it very efficiency on terminal.

Also you could check out tornado [Running and deploying](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html) section for more suggestions.